# How to search in multiple collections in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections User and UserType :-

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({ 

     username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },

   userType: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "UserType",
      required: true,
   },
});

 var UserTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
   {
      type: String,
      type_code: Number,
      type_description: String,
   },
   { timestamps: true }
);
```

I want to search user based on username and typecode which is in UserType Collection.
I tried this code: -

```
    User.findOne({
  username: mobileNumber,
  userType: { type_code: userTypeCode },
})
   .populate("userType");
```

please correct this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must to filter out populate results, with `match` option
In your case answer would be::

```
User.findOne({
  username: mobileNumber,
}).populate({
  path: "userType",
  match: { type_code: userTypeCode },
});
```

you can check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate)